# Laravel Dusk works chronologically but doesn't with for loop

Tags: laravel, selenium, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I have a select element and it has years as values such as `'2019', '2018', '2017'...`

If I try using them one after another like this it works:

```
$browser->select('year', '2019');
$browser->select('year', '2018');
$browser->select('year', '2017');
```

However, if I try to use it with a for loop, it doesn't work

```
$years = ['2019', '2018', '2017'];

foreach ($years as $year) {
   Log::info($year);

   $browser->select('year', $year);
}
```

> // logs 2019 and then crashes
>
> (Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\StaleElementReferenceException(code: 0): stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I tried using `waitFor()`, `pause(5000)` or even `waitForReload()` but nothing has changed (except waitForReload crashed because it waited for 5 seconds without change)

Comment: Does selecting an option execute any JavaScript? Why do you select multiple values like this?

Comment: I am using dusk for scraping data from a 3rd party page. When I select an option from the selector, it shows new data below the select (and not via Javascript, but via reload instead). By 'below the select', I don't mean it creates new options; but it shows a different table data below.

Comment: Doesn't work. How did you try `waitFor()`?

Comment: `->waitFor('#the_id')`

Comment: Can you try `waitFor('select[name=year]')`?

Comment: Just tried, same issue - however, I can confirm that the selector works

Comment: The exception is definitely coming from the `$browser->select('year', $year);` line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178038/discussion-between-senty-and-jonas-staudenmeir).